# can we convert the angular8 component into a standalone JS file with routing/navigation?

Tags: angularjs, angular8

i am working on a angular 8 application , when user clicks on a button it should redirect to a vendor portal which is completely a different webapp (diff Url), when user redirect to vendor page , user should see the same header ,footer and navigation what i have in my web application. but the vendor application is on angularJS(1.x).

so my question is can we convert the Angular8 project/component into a standalone JS file and ask the vendor to load the JS file in their application ?  this JS file should contain the logic to replace/inject with in their page. for ex: we ask the vendor to create a html element with ID name "custom-header" in their page and ask them to add my JS file (hosted on CDN ) on their landing page, and in my JS file we need to write a logic to look for "custom-header" Id and replace with our content ?

so can we write custom code in our Angular8 application and export it as a standalone JS file ?

Note: my Header/Navigration/footer angular components are  shared components , i want to use the same component in my webapp as well as vendor component

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shortest answer: **No.**

Here's the '*been there done that answer*':
I've spent time trying to make things backward compatible and it's rarely worth the effort. I have written alot of angularJS and Angular2+ code and believe that any time you spend trying to crowbar a solution here would be better spent just making the angularJS module. AngularJS a simple, fast framework and you could have your result quickly. Alot/most of your logic/html could be directly ported over with small mods.

Here's the `TL;DR` answer:
I hate to ever say '*You can't do that*' with technology because I'm usually wrong... but you can't do that directly. Well, I guess you could use iframes but that's not a good idea.

While there is a path to incrementally merge angularJS into an Angular 8 app, the same is not true of the reverse. However, you should be able to leverage much of the existing logic from the A8 app into a module that angularJS could just import.

Without seeing how intricate the A8 component is, angularJS is alot simpler and it's relatively easy to throw together a controller/directive/view single import. I don't see a clear path to automatically updating the aJS code when you update your angular 8.